# where does https on apache get it's configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, defaults

So originally my host (mediatemple dv) has two default directories for the roots:

1)httpdocs/
2)httpsdocs/

In the conf directory I changed the vhosts.conf and httpd.include and others to change from httpdocs to custom folders.

Now I installed a new ssl certificate and https://example.com goes to the default page located at httpsdocs.

I'm just wondering where configurations for apache are stored for ssl.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a "normal" install, there's typically /etc/httpd/ that contains configuration. Specifically, there's /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf which is the "main" configuration file, and it specifies that all .conf files in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ are then included.

In my configs, I have /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf which does all of the https-specific configuration, but there's a wide degree of flexibility for the administrator to decide on.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll configure the SSL settings that are not necessarily specific to a given host (e.g. `SSLCipherSuites`) in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` (or similar in other distributions), but configure what's specific to a given host in its own `VirtualHost` (with the appropriate port), more or less like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # ...

        SSLEngine       on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/host.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/host.key

        DocumentRoot /path/to/https/root
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        # ...

        DocumentRoot /path/to/plain-http/root
</VirtualHost>
```

You could put the part with  into its own file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` or within `ssl.conf`.

It depends on the distribution. On Debian/Ubuntu, you'll probably have the general SSL configuration in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf` and the site/virtualhost specific configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/some-name.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to create a **vhost_ssl.conf** file pointing to the new Document Root in `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/conf/` and then run `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng -u --vhost-name=example.com` for Plesk.